# Database Design for class prerequisites

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am currently working on a sample class registration system for which I need to maintain class prerequisites. I have to display class prerequisites on page as a boolean expression.
Example:
If a student is viewing Class A, prerequisites must be displayed as (B AND C) OR D

I am not sure how to handle this.

Design so far:
A Class have many sections.
Class(*deptartment, class_number*, description)

Italics are primary keys. Any suggestions how to handle prerequisites??

Example data for course:
(CMSC,201,Programming 1)
(CMSC,202,Programming 2)
(CMSC,203,Discrete Structures)
(CMSC,341,Data Structures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to duffymo's suggestion of a one-to-many relationship, add grouping to that relation. The group ID would then be your parenthesis. So your table may look like this:

```
class_id, prereq_group, prereq_id
1, 1, B
1, 1, C
1, 2, D
```

The prereq_group only needs to be unique within the class_id and could be a sequential number. If prereqs have the same group id, then they would be AND. Different group ids would be an OR. So in the above example, it would be (B AND C) OR (D).

Comment: Yep, this makes perfect sense. Thanks Brent and duffymo :)

Answer (score 1):

Section is irrelevant for prerequisites.

It sounds like a one-to-many relationship.

I'm not sure if a passing grade needs to be part of your prerequisites.  If yes, you've got more work to do, because you'll need Student and ReportCard tables to manage Prerequisites.

Comment: You are right section is irrelevant. No, passing grade doesn't have to be a part of prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a non trivial design case...As far as iv seen DB designs there can be no single join condition without losing 1NF on this.

A suggested solution which can run into multi self joins without losing 1NF-

Assuming by class u mean course...
prerequisites(prerequisite_id(pk),class_no*(fk),relationship,Linked_Prerequisites(fk)*)

if Linked_Prerequisites is null we can go on using  to club all rows available under a particular class_no to find all prerequisites.

eg

```
Prerequisites(prerequisite_id,class_with_prerequisite,class_id_of_prerequisite, relationship, linked_prerequisites)
1,1,2,and,2
2,1,3,null,null
3,1,4,or,null

--------------

Class(*deptartment, class_number*(pk), description) 
12,1,classA
12,2,classB
12,3,ClassC
12,4,ClassD
--------------
```

Using this you can create a directed graph. Initially u can select data from prerequisites such that they have non null data and then join it with itself to create a hierarchy within itself.

If you maintain the data yourself u can manipulate this to work at a single level directed graph with which u will have to write just a one level join.